# Exponentiation of an array raised to the power of another array?

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures

Consider I have a data structure called **VeryBig** having size and array of int type which can accommodate huge numbers.

I have an array **base->arr** having elements 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 and another array **exponent->arr** having elements 1,2,3,4,5,6

```
struct VeryBig{
    int* arr;
    int size;
}VeryBig;
```

Is it possible to calculate the exponentiation of base raised to exponent without converting the array into actual numbers (which rules out in case of working with large integers) and calculate the result to a new array **result** of the same structure.

Though I can try to understand the logic in other languages as well, any help in C is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to interpret each array as the digits of a decimal numeral, so the array containing 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 represents 987654321, and you want to compute one of these numbers raised to the power of the other of these numbers (in some array form), so 987654321^123456? There are ways to do this. The result will have 1,110,438 digits. Is that what you want?

Comment: Exactly. I wanted to calculate power of 987654321^123456. But pow() or any other functions donot help with such a large numbers

Comment: Use the same method as pencil and paper

Comment: @stark: What method do you use to raise a number to the power of 123456 on paper?

Comment: If you want to implement your own extended precision package, start with addition/subtraction/multiplication.  Then use those to implement integer exponentiation.

Comment: @eric Are you aware that people did math before computers?

Comment: @stark: Yes, but I do not recall ever being taught a method of raising a number to the power of 123456 in any ordinary arithmetic class where paper would have been used. Again, what method do you use to raise a number to the power of 123456 on paper?

Comment: I think it's safe to say that if there is a way, which there probably is, it won't be simpler or faster than using some bignum package. You would need a powerful reason like super tight space requirements to want to do it any other way.

Comment: @stark I do understand that we can multiply the base to itself, exponent number of times, but i would doubt that in a case having huge number of digits (say 1 million digits raised to 5 million digits). The only way I see is to create a data structure that stores my number as digits in array and work through it.

Comment: You really want to calculate numbers with trillions of digits? What on Earth for? Isn't there another way for you to get what you need? By the way, you can exponentiate by n with O(log(n)) multiplications. Google Exponentiation By Squaring.

Comment: If you want to represent your number as decimal digits, you will need to keep many arrays and do a prohibitive number of multiply-adds. Much better to use a binary package like gmp.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/564052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly simple algorithm is:

- Write a routine that multiplies two `VeryBig` numbers. Given two operands, it computes how much space is needed for the product, at most, allocates memory, and multiplies the numbers using the algorithm for multiplication taught in elementary school.
- Write a routine that divides a `VeryBig` number by two. It should return a `VeryBig` number that is the quotient and a single digit that is the remainder, 0 or 1.
- Write a routine using the algorithm below to exponentiate numbers.

1. Start with input operands `base` and `exponent` of type `VeryBig`.
2. Set a `VeryBig` number named `t` to 1. `t` will be used to accumulate the result.
3. If `exponent` is zero, stop. `t` is the result.
4. Divide `exponent` by 2, setting `exponent` to the quotient and `remainder` to the remainder.
5. If `remainder` is 1, set to to `t` multiplied by `base`.
6. Set `base` to `base` multiplied by `base`.
7. Go to step 3.

The basic premise of this algorithm is that we may consider the exponent *e* as a binary numeral, say with bits *e*<sub>3</sub>*e*<sub>2</sub>*e*<sub>1</sub>*e*<sub>0</sub>. Then *b*<sup>*e*</sup> = *b*<sup>*e*<sub>3</sub>*e*<sub>2</sub>*e*<sub>1</sub>*e*<sub>0</sub></sup> = *b*<sup>2<sup>3</sup>*e*<sub>3</sub>+2<sup>2</sup>*e*<sub>2</sub>+2<sup>1</sup>*e*<sub>1</sub>+2<sup>0</sup>*e*<sub>0</sub></sup> = (*b*<sup>2<sup>3</sup></sup>)<sup>*e*<sub>3</sub></sup>•(*b*<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup>)<sup>*e*<sub>2</sub></sup>•(*b*<sup>2<sup>1</sup></sup>)<sup>*e*<sub>1</sub></sup>•(*b*<sup>2<sup>0</sup></sup>)<sup>*e*<sub>0</sub></sup>. For any bits *e*<sub>*i*</sub> that are zero, the corresponding term is 1, so *b*<sup>*e*</sup> is just the product of the various *b*<sup>2<sup>*i*</sup></sup> for which the corresponding bits are one. And that is what the algorithm computes: Multiplying `base` by itself tracks *b*<sup>2<sup>*i*</sup></sup> as the loop progresses, and, for each bit of the exponent that is one, that term is multiplied into the accumulating product, `t`.

Comment: Yes, this definitely works. Thank You